# Zarr open() returns FSPathExistNotDir error

Tags: zarr

When I run `zarr.open('result.zarr', mode='r')` I get the following error:

> FSPathExistNotDir: path exists but is not a directory: %r

According to the example in the Zarr documentation located at https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#persistent-arrays, this zarr.open() function should return a zarr.core.Array:

```
z2 = zarr.open('data/example.zarr', mode='r')
np.all(z1[:] == z2[:])
```

How come the `zarr.open()` function is looking for a directory in my case?

Comment: I've also tried the following and I get the same error.                                                     
`z = zarr.open_array('./result.zarr', mode='w')`

Comment: Is result.zarr just a single file? If so, what type? By default, zarr creates and expects a directory.

Comment: Yes it's just a zarray single file.

Comment: With `import zarr` that should just work (and does for me). It produces one file on disk `data/example.zarr/.zarray` and if you set values, then numbered chunks will be produced.

Answer (score 0):

I see my confusion. For me, `example.zarr` is the name of the file (it seems I wrongly named it), and not a directory.

I was also confused because zarr.open() *creates* a zarray but does not *open* an existing zarray like the function name implies.

From kaggle.com/kneroma/zarr-files-and-l5kit-data-for-dummies:

`z1 = zarr.open('data/example.zarr', mode='w', shape=(10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000), dtype='i4') z1`

> The array above will store its configuration metadata and all
> compressed chunk data in a directory called ‘data/example.zarr’
> relative to the current working directory.
> The zarr.convenience.open() function provides a convenient way to
> create a new persistent array or continue working with an existing
> array.